# How to insert a pair of elements as single elements in a set container?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, containers, std-pair

My simple code is like this :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>

using namespace std;

void main() {
     set<string,string> myset;
     myset.insert(pair<string,string>("abc","def"));
     cout<<myset.size()<<endl;
}
```

i.e. I want to take pairs as set elements. But this code generates error. In map container also I'm facing difficulties to insert distinct pairs as elements. But in case of `("abc","def")` and `("abc","ghe")`, for same key value i.e. "abc", the second pair cannot be taken into the container even though the pairs are distinct for the second element of the pairs .

How to change my code to get the job done ?

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` is declared as:

```
template <class Key, class Compare = less<Key>,
          class Allocator = allocator<Key> >
    class set;
```

The set contains elements of type `Key`, sorted using the second template parameter. So you can't define a `std::set< std::string, std::string >` to hold pairs of strings.

`std::map` can be used to store pairs of `std::string`s, but the keys are unique. So you won't be able to store multiple pairs with the same key (the first element of the pair).

If you want to store pairs, you can do so directly, by defining the container like this:

```
std::set< std::pair<std::string, std::string> > mySet;
```